Schtasks - Error: The parameter is incorrect. (14,8): UserId:
I am working on a script to automate the ability to use schtasks to test managing remote Windows Scheduled Tasks.  I have a specific test task that I created on another server.  I am able to query that task without issue.  However, when I attempt to do a change, I get:
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
(14,8):UserId:

I know this error can happen from time to time, however, the documentation for schtasks is poor when it comes to error handling, and the resolution for the various values ((14,8) for example) is not clear.
First, my command:
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks /change /s target-win /u target-win\localadmin /p h /rp h /tn testtask

This is a lab environment, and for ease of testing, the actual password is literally just the letter 'h'.  From a syntax standpoint, the above is correct.  'Target-win', the other server, is the correct hostname and there are no resolution issues.  My command prompt session on the source server is running in the context of the 'localadmin' user ('localadmin' is a local admin account on 'target-win').
The xml of the scheduled task:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2024-07-22T20:47:34.042254</Date>
    <Author>TARGET-WIN\Administrator</Author>
    <URI>\testtask</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers />
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
      <UserId>target-win\localadmin</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>

The first issue I had found was that the UserId (line 12 in a text editor) was originally set to the SID of 'target-win\localadmin'.  To fix this, and ensure that the task was updated in taskschd.msc, I exported the task, edited the xml and change the SID to the username (confirming it matches exactly what is in lusrmgr.msc), and then imported the task, deleting the old one.  For confirmation, I then rebooted the server.  However, this did not change the error.
I am unsure of what else to try.  I have already done other steps such as creating a brand new task via command line on the source server as well as command line on the target server.  I've tested using different admin accounts.  No matter what, I can't get past this error.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Have you tried uppercase the domain of your localadmin ?
I would try "TARGET-WIN\localadmin" instead of "target-win\localadmin".

Unfortunately no luck.  Worth a shot of course, but no change in the error.
